# Use Firewall Builder as a GUI for iptables

Tags: firewall

I want to use Firewall Builder as a GUI to iptables on local machine. I don't know how to setup program or firewall preferences to install and run script with Install button. Basically FWBuilder was designed to deploy firewall script via SSH on remote machine. How to do it on local machine without need to install SSH server?